# How to get the height and width of an object?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I want to calculate the height and width of individual objects, but I'm getting 0 value.

Here's an image that consists of the objects I'm looking at:

[image]

I tried the following code:

```
clear all;
close all;
clc;
%% start
filename = 'untitled.png'; 
I = imread(filename);
info = imfinfo(filename);
thres = graythresh(I);
I2 = ~(im2bw(I, thres));
cmp = bwconncomp(I2);
S = regionprops(cmp, {'BoundingBox'});
bbox = vertcat(S.BoundingBox);
x = bbox(:,3);
y = bbox(:,4);
res = info.ResolutionUnit;
resX = info.XResolution;
resY = info.YResolution;
if strcmp(res, 'Inch')
lebar = 2.54 * x / resX;
tinggi = 2.54 * y / resY;
else
lebar = x / resX;
tinggi = y / resY;
end
fprintf('X Resolution = %.2f %s\n', resX, res);
fprintf('Y Resolution = %.2f %s\n', resY, res);
disp('Size of Object:');
fprintf('Width = %.2f cm\n', lebar);
fprintf('Height = %.2f cm\n', tinggi);
```

Also how do I remove the rectangle in the image?

Comment: what about showing us that untitled image so we can try it out? Thanks!

Comment: If the ellipse can be fully contained inside a rectangle and the ellipse isn't subject to rotation, then the width and height of the ellipse is simply the same as the bounding box that contains it.

Comment: Your images don't look like ellipses at all.  They look like shapes of arbitrary makeup.

Comment: tht's correct sir. i need to modify my program to get ellipse.i need the width n height of objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corrected code

```
clear all;
close all;
clc;
%% start
filename = 'untitled.png'; 
I = imread(filename);
info = imfinfo(filename);
thres = graythresh(I);
I2 = im2bw(I, thres);
cmp = bwconncomp(I2);
S = regionprops(cmp, {'BoundingBox'});
bbox = vertcat(S.BoundingBox);
x = bbox(:,3);
y = bbox(:,4);
res = info.ResolutionUnit;
resX = info.XResolution;
resY = info.YResolution;
if strcmp(res, 'Inch')
lebar = 2.54 * x / resX;
tinggi = 2.54 * y / resY;
else
lebar = x / resX;
tinggi = y / resY;
end
fprintf('X Resolution = %.4f %s\n', resX, res);
fprintf('Y Resolution = %.4f %s\n', resY, res);
disp('Size of Object:');
fprintf('Width = %.4f cm\n', lebar);
fprintf('Height = %.4f cm\n', tinggi);
%% end
```